# Examples of reductive group $G$ and primes $p$ where $G$ ramifies at $p$

Tags: algebraic-groups, ramification, reductive-groups

I'm looking for an example (as simple as possible) of a reductive group $G$ (over a number field) for which we can compute each prime number at which $G$ ramifies.

Comment: What do you mean by "$G$ ramifies" ?

Comment: I mean that if $G$ is definied over $K$ then $G$ is unramified at $\frak{p}$ when $G\times K_{\frak{p}}$ is split up to an unramified extension of $K_{\frak{p}}$.

Comment: @MarsaultChabat That's probably not the correct definition -- you probably want that it's additionally quasi-split at $\mf{p}$. In any case, have you considered $G=D^\times$ for a central-simple $K$-algebra?

Comment: Oh yes indeed! I will look at your example thank you @AlexYoucis